# Javascript remove bom from document

Tags: javascript, document, byte-order-mark

I'm wondering if I can remove bom character like

```html
 &#65279;
```

from my document using javascript?

```html
<body style="background: rgb(48, 48, 48);">&#65279;




<script>
```

Comment: I am guessing you probably can, but we can't with the information provided.

Comment: What you mean ?

I tried something like : 
var Reg = /0xFEFF/i;

   console.log(Reg.test(document.body.innerHTML));
   document.body.innerHTML.replace(Reg, '');

Test() return true, but replace() didn't replace anything.

Comment: and replacing the whole innerHTML is a bad idea if you have event handlers and such attached to it. Is the character in a certain location of the document?

Comment: At least one of them is a big issue. Right after the body tag.

Comment: So it is after the opening tag? Like can you actually show us a snipplet of code?

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(String.fromCharCode(65279), "" )` would work, but it is not a good solution.

Comment: What would be a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue.

The default solution is to save the document with UTF without BOM.

But unexpectedly, I had pasted my JS code in the console and the red bullet had been shown. So I deleted them and copied the code from the console.
[image]